# How to extend already defined lists and maps in Spring application context?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Imagine a staged application context with different phases. We start with an early phase to define the necessary infrastructure. The xml application contexts are loaded sequentially.

The reason to split up these files is an extension/plugin mechanism.

**Stage 01-default-configuration.xml**

We prepare and declare the map with id `exampleMapping` to enhance them later with data.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="[...]">

  <util:map id="exampleMapping" />
</beans>
```

**Stage 02-custom-configuration.xml** *(optional)*

We configure the `exampleMapping` and add an entry.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="[...]">

  <util:map id="exampleMapping">
    <entry key="theKey" value="theValue" />
  </util:map>
</beans>
```

**Stage 03-make-use-of-configuration.xml** *(mandatory)*

Uses the defined map `exampleMapping`, whether it's configured customly or it's still the empty declared map.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="[...]">

    <bean id="exampleService" class="com.stackoverflow.example.ExampleService">
       <property name="mapping" ref="exampleMapping" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The problem here is, that it's not possible to add entries to the `exampleMapping` map after the first stage. Spring throws an exception that the map with id `exampleMapping` already exists. If we leave out the first stage the map is undeclared and the third stage can't resolve `exampleMapping` which also produces an exception.

How can I solve this issue? I read [Collection merging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements-merging) (spring docs) but this didn't helped. Is it possible to add values later to maps/lists before using them?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be enhanced with entries after the first stage"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* define `exampleMapping` is the second definition is in a separate file, and you use `<import resource="..."/>` to import one file into another, but it's a fragile approach, and easily broken.

I suggest a more robust strategy.  Replace the `exampleMapping` with a `Registry` class, which in turn contains and manages the mappings:

```
public MappingRegistry<K,V> {

   private final Map<K,V> mappings = new HashMap<K,V>();

   public void addMapping(K key, V value) {
      mappings.put(key, value);
   }

   public Map<K,V> getMappings() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableMap(mappings);
   }
}
```

Then, write a class which registers a mapping with the registry:

```
public class MappingRegistrar<K,V> {

   private final MappingRegistry<K,V> registry;

   private K key;
   private V value;

   @Autowired
   public MappingRegistrar(MappingRegistry<K,V> registry) {
      this.registry = registry;
   }

   public void setKey(K key) {
      this.key = key;
   }

   public void setValue(V value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void registerMapping() {
      registry.addMapping(key, value);
   }
}
```

The your config becomes something like this:

```
<bean id="mappingRegistry" class="com.xyz.MappingRegistry"/>

<bean id="mappingA" class="com.xyz.MappingRegistrar" p:key="keyA" p:value="valueA"/>
<bean id="mappingB" class="com.xyz.MappingRegistrar" p:key="keyB" p:value="valueB"/>
<bean id="mappingC" class="com.xyz.MappingRegistrar" p:key="keyC" p:value="valueC"/>
```

These mappings can now be scattered throughout your config in any way you see fit, and they will self-assemble.  `ExampleServcie` is then injected with the `MappingRegistry` and extracts the mappings accordingly.

It's a bit more work than what you already have, but it's a lot more flexible and less error prone.  This is particularly valuable if you're trying to build an extensible framework of some kind; you want to put fewer constraints on how people use it.

Comment: I already used this mechanism to provide an extensible feature for special kind of filter/value-providers. Thought this would be to much overhead and there is an easier way to achieve this for lists/maps. Apparently not. I will implement it like you proposed. Maybe we will see such a spring-feature in future? Thank you!

Comment: @codevour: I don't think this is overkill, I think this is good design. It's more robust, more explicit, and more readable than using a naked Map, in my opinion.

Comment: You may be right, this could be a very generic way of doing this, the beans could also be anonymous. Thought a little about that, this fits well for my approach. Thank you again.

Answer (score 16):

Both `map` and `list` has this attribute named `merge=true|false` for merging two lists. Alternatively you can use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` for calling already defined list's add method to add extra items later.

Let's go over your example.

1) First the second scenario with `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`. Instead of defining the way you do, I defined your beans a little differently.

```
<bean class="java.util.HashMap" id="exampleMapping">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <map>
            <entry key="theKey" value="theValue"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="exampleService" class="com.stackoverflow.example.ExampleService">
    <property name="mapping" ref="exampleMapping"/>
</bean>
```

In another application content file, you can do the following to extend the map.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="exampleMapping"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <map id="exampleMapping">
            <entry key="theKey2" value="theValue2"/>
            <entry key="theKey3" value="theValue3"/>
            <map>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2) Now the first scenario. For this one, I just found something on page http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=53358

```
<bean id="commonData" class="A">
    <property name="map">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="1" value="1"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="data" class="A" parent="commonData">
    <property name="map">
        <util:map merge="true">
            <entry key="2" value="2"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example? Unfortunately I don't get it running.

Comment: I updated the answer and gave an example for both of the options.

Comment: I think the first scenario isn't a great design for this approach and sounds very dirty to me. The second one is a bit obfuscating, I think writing a registry as skaffmann mentioned will be the best. Thank you for your answer and explanation!

Comment: It is also the same thing actually, you just make `MappingRegistrar` do it for you instead of calling put method by yourself, anyways personally I don't like coding for this kind of things if I can do it declaratively.

Comment: You're right, but if it's possible to avoid reflection and a instable way of using an API I would vote for the coding way. In this case the #putAll() method will not change, but using another API could be instable, don't you think?

Comment: u'r right in case of an API change you can detect one of them at compile time and the other one at runtime. It is not the golden hammer. I use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` to increase modularity of applications with multiple modules (jars), all you have to do is to package the jar with the webapp, spring will bootstrap the context, the beans will register themselves to wherever needed. I can not provide registries for everything at least I don't want to.

Comment: Basically, this should be the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!